# Add sub-condition in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not sure what is the proper name to give to this condition in the where clause. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Basically, I have an order table with the following columns.

MyOrderTable:

```
OrderAmount Paid    OrderDate
100         Y       2016-08-10 21:15:52.000
120         N       2016-08-10 20:15:12.000
300         Y       2016-08-09 11:10:22.000
500         Y       2016-06-09 10:10:54.000
125         N       2016-06-09 09:15:13.000 
325         N       2015-11-09 09:15:13.000
```

Currently, I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, OrderDate) TheYear, DATEPART(Month, OrderDate) TheMonth,
       SUM(ISNULL(OrderAmount, 0)) as SumOrderAmount
FROM MyOrderTable
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2016
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, OrderDate), DATEPART(Month, OrderDate)
ORDER BY TheYear, TheMonth
```

The result returned from the above SQL is like the following:

```
TheYear     TheMonth    SumOrderAmount
2016        6           625
2016        8           520
```

How can I query also the SumOrderAmount where the row is Paid='Y'? I want to return the following from the SQL:

```
TheYear     TheMonth    SumOrderAmount  PaidSumOrderAmount
2016        6           625             500
2016        8           520             400
```

How can I do that? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, OrderDate) TheYear, DATEPART(Month, OrderDate) TheMonth,
       SUM(ISNULL(OrderAmount, 0)) as SumOrderAmount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Paid = 'Y' THEN OrderAmount ELSE 0 END) as PaidOrderAmount
FROM MyOrderTable
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2016
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, OrderDate), DATEPART(Month, OrderDate)
ORDER BY TheYear, TheMonth;
```

You probably don't need the `ISNULL()` in `SUM()`.  In SQL, `NULL` values are ignored in the `SUM()` aggregation function.

Comment: So after that being said, he doesn't need the `ELSE 0` too :)

Comment: @sagi . . . Au contraire.  That is needed to prevent `NULL` values when there are no matches, because it is reasonable to assume that a month would have no paid amounts.  On the other hand, if all paid amounts for a month were `NULL`, then it would be needed for the total as well.  That seems unlikely given the provided data.

Comment: If OP has months with no paid sales, that's probably a bigger issue than a NULL value instead of 0.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks so much for helping.
Anyway, why am getting a -1 for my question there?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression to do a conditional `SUM()`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, OrderDate) TheYear, DATEPART(Month, OrderDate) TheMonth,
       SUM(ISNULL(OrderAmount, 0)) as SumOrderAmount,
       SUM(case when Paid='Y' then OrderAmount end)
FROM MyOrderTable
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2016
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, OrderDate), DATEPART(Month, OrderDate)
ORDER BY TheYear, TheMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this clause on select:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Paid='Y' THEN OrderAmount ELSE 0 END) AS PaidSumOrderAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, OrderDate) TheYear, DATEPART(Month, OrderDate) TheMonth,
       SUM(ISNULL(OrderAmount, 0)) as SumOrderAmount,Paid
FROM MyOrderTable
WHERE (YEAR(OrderDate) = 2016) and (Paid = 'Y')
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, OrderDate), DATEPART(Month, OrderDate)
ORDER BY TheYear, TheMonth
```

Comment: Note that OP wants to keep the SumOrderAmount column as before.

Comment: @jarlh sorry i d'ont understand english verry well

Comment: @jarlh your answer and Gordon Linoff is the same

Comment: I've noticed that too, but I typed a bit faster this time!

Comment: @jarlh sorry bro it happen to me many times.and im verry angry ,Some people d'ont respect me because of my mother language, and has caused me problems and I do not have any friends and do not speak with one.